# Which one i should use grunt-cache-breaker? or grunt-usemin? for caching issue

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, grunt-usemin

I tried using grunt-usemin, but it did not work. I tried grunt-cache-breaker it works fine. But js filename wont change in grunt-cache-breaker. It will just change the reference in html. Which is good among two for solving caching issue for angularjs application.

Answer (score 0):

Grunt-usemin works fine but you need to give the exact file path reference of stylesheet and script files in the HTML file then only grunt-usemin works.